# how to present the HTML output to the view

Tags: html, xcode, ipad, dynamic-html

i hav an html file which displays table view ,how to load this on the ipad view ..

and i want to enter the values to the fields of table view in html o/p....

any ideas ..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for displaying a local html file onto the iOS device.

The code below will load `index.html` from your project folder:

```
[webView loadRequest:
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
        [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"] 
            isDirectory:NO]
    ]
];
```

Comment: thanks, and i want to modify the values of the html o/p file   for ex: i want to place some attributes to table

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by modify by "modify the values of the html o/p file."

Comment: i am displaying empty tabular form ,is like report ..i want to dynamically fill those fields in table with data

Comment: if i hav a html tags in string how to load webview with string